Can't deploy model from Azure AI Foundry to Copilot Studio
In Azure AI Foundry, I have a deployed model in the playground (gpt-4o-mini) and provided instruction prompt and several examples. I have tried both adding an uploaded file as data as well as using the sample "hotels-sample" data (in order to be sure it wasn't something to do with the uploaded data file). If I don't add data, I only have the option to deploy to a web app (this is expected) and when I add data (either type), I then get the option to deploy "... to a new copilot in Copilot Studio". However, in both cases of added data, when I select this menu option, I get the following message:
"Cannot deploy to Power Virtual Agents with current configuration. Please remove your data to continue."
I'm not sure how to resolve this problem and can't seem to find anyone else who has run into this previously.

